# Should Actuator custom endpoint be annotated on Controller level or Service level?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I was trying to understand what is the criteria to decide for **custom endpoints** 'Should I annotate Actuator custom endpoint on Controller level or Service level.
In what situation, I annotate at Controller level and in what situation I should annotate at service level method.

Comment: Why would you be defining the actuator endpoint? The library defines it.

Comment: I mean I have to annotate using actuator library itself for Service level I can use 'EndPoint' annotation or Controller level I should 'RestControllerEndPoint' annotation

Comment: my question is that I can use both annotation but in which I should prefer controller level annnotation and in what situtation service level annotation. You can rephrase the question if it doesn't mean what I want to ask

Comment: One more thing, I meant for custom endpoints not the ones which are defined llibrary already

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't realize you meant custom endpoints. I'm not sure but I think the difference is if you want them to be [exposed via JMX or HTTP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html).

Comment: but i think both can be exposed as http but not sure if controller be expose as JMX

Comment: It's my understanding, from the document I linked to, that an endpoint in a controller is not exposed as JMX.